# Can't view this site in Chrome (Getting Aw Snap! error)

Tags: css, google-chrome

The site in question is http://traceyj.posterous.com/

Using Chrome, it shows the Aw Snap error almost instantaneously. I do not have much programming experience to troubleshoot this - I've tried viewing the site in a css validator but it looks like the solution isn't as easy as I thought it would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Opens fine for me in chrome 14

Comment: Well... I'm not getting an Aw Snap error, but I am getting a ton of 414 errors (Request-URI Too Long).

Comment: What a mess... I tried in Safari which is also a Webkit browser like Chrome and it almost crashed.

Comment: What exactly is the issue/question here?  What is a "aw snap" error?  What does your console say?

Answer (score 1):

'Aw Snap' is an error given by Chrome when a webpage 'crashes'.
https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95669&hl=en-US

That's a pretty high level description however, so it's not much use for troubleshooting.

OK, in Chrome, using the DOM inspection and script debugging tools (bring these up before you load the page in question), I can see that there are some bad requests (HTTP status 400) to http://traceyj.posterous.com/posts/deferred_content.jsonp with an insanely long query string.  By insanely long, I mean close to 1KB:

`GET [http]://traceyj.posterous.com/posts/deferred_content.jsonp?authenticity_token= gmiqsYI36417dgFhq9VF%2BoiN05dYXzPToUXXc3UPqE0%3D&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Ftraceyj.poste rous.com%2F&posts=%255B%257B%2522post_id%2522%253A72384043%252C%2522post_is_private% 2522%253Afalse%252C%2522post_url_slug%2522%253A%25222673652011-satsep24%2522%252C%25 22user_id%2522%253A65911%257D%252C%257B%2522post_id%2522%253A72383955%252C%2522post_ is_private%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522post_url_slug%2522%253A%25222663652011-frisep23`...
*ad nauseum*

These errors also show in the web console in Firefox.

Now as far as I can tell, posterous.com is a site that provides the tools to do what you're doing: presenting a whole bunch of photographs etc.  Unless you are customizing something on the page, it seems likely that the dev team at posterous.com would be best suited to helping you.

Other things you might try would be to shorten the list of items that you're displaying on each page.  In fact, going to http://traceyj.posterous.com/?page=6, works (at least for now) in Chrome - and I suspect it's simply because the query string isn't so insanely long, which is likely the cause of the 414 errors that Joseph mentioned.